# Django ListView ignore Order_by in get_Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

i'm trying to edit order in a listView through get_queryset() funcion and using order_by()
when i try print generated query it's ignore order_by query and uses only the default order in Meta class inside my model class
Do you know why that appens?
Here my view.py file

```
class TagsListView(ListView):
    
    model = Tag

    paginate_by = 250
    ordering = ['-tag']

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        queryset.order_by('slug',  )

        # se presente type nell'url aggiunge il filtro 
        category = self.request.GET.get("category", None)
        # type = self.kwargs.get('type', None)
        if category :
            queryset = queryset.filter( category=category )

        search = self.request.GET.get("search", None)
        if search :
            queryset = queryset.filter( tag__icontains=search )

        print('test ordering')
        queryset.order_by('slug', 'tag', 'date' )

        print(queryset.query.__str__())

        return queryset #aggiustare l'url
```

that is my model file

```
# Create your models here.
class Tag(models.Model):

    GENERIC         = 0
    CONSOL          = 1
    SOCIETA         = 2
    SAGA            = 3
    CAT             = 4
    ALTRO           = 5
    CATEGORIES = [
            (GENERIC,'Generico'),
            (CONSOL,'Consol'),
            (SOCIETA,'Sport'),
            (SAGA,'Salute'),
            (CAT,'Categorie'),
            (ALTRO,'Tempo Libero'),
        ]

    tag = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=CATEGORIES, blank=True, default=GENERIC)
    custom = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date', 'tag') #ordinamento degli elementi
        pass

    def __str__(self):  #metodo righiesto
        return self.tag + " - " + self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("tags:tag-detail", args=[self.slug,]) #article-deatil preso da urls.py

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug = slugify(self.tag, allow_unicode=True)
        pass
```

inside console log i got that sql print

```
SELECT `tags_tag`.`id`, `tags_tag`.`tag`, `tags_tag`.`slug`, `tags_tag`.`date`, `tags_tag`.`category`, `tags_tag`.`custom` FROM `tags_tag` ORDER BY `tags_tag`.`date` DESC, `tags_tag`.`tag` ASC
```

instead of

```
SELECT `tags_tag`.`id`, `tags_tag`.`tag`, `tags_tag`.`slug`, `tags_tag`.`date`, `tags_tag`.`category`, `tags_tag`.`custom` FROM `tags_tag` ORDER BY `tags_tag`.`slug` ASC, `tags_tag`.`tag` ASC, `tags_tag`.`date` ASC
```

Comment: If you implement the `get_queryset` itself, it will *not* order it, since the logic to order the queryset is implement by the "parent" `get_queryset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement the `get_queryset` itself, it will *not* order it, since the logic to order the queryset is implement by the "parent" `get_queryset`.

You thus will need to add the `.order_by` clause yourself. Since `QuerySet`s are (more or less) *immutable* you thus should construct an ordered variant of the queryset with:

```
#    ↓ assign to the queryset
queryset = queryset.order_by('slug', 'tag', 'date')
```

The view thus looks like:

```
class TagsListView(ListView):
    model = Tag
    paginate_by = 250

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        category = self.request.GET.get('category', None)
        if category :
            queryset = queryset.filter( category=category )

        search = self.request.GET.get("search", None)
        if search :
            queryset = queryset.filter(tag__icontains=search)
        queryset = queryset.order_by('slug', 'tag', 'date')
        return queryset
```

Comment: Did this change in Django 2 or later? I'm busy upgrading from 1.11 and in 1.11 it uses the ordering defined in the model's meta class

Comment: @Kritz: it will respect the ordering of the `Meta` of the model (unless you specify an order yourself of course), the point is that the `ordering` in the `ListView` will not be respected, since the `get_queryset` of a `ListView` does the ordering, and if you override this, then of course it is not oredered according to the `ListView`s ordering.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused as in the upgrade process we are now getting "Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list" warnings in a lot of list views where we do in fact override the get_queryset method. Did a) something change after Django 1.11 or b) was the issue always there and Django is only now alerting me about it?

Comment: @Kritz: no that did not change w.r.t. Django-1.11. If there was an `ordering` in the `ListView` and an override of `get_queryset`, then that `ordering` will not work in both Django-1.11 and a later version.

Comment: I did a bit more digging and it looks like there is an annotate clause that is causing this warning. Strangely when it is there the "ORDER BY" is removed from the query. Any ideas why?

Comment: Turns out adding an annotate clause removes order_by from Django 3 - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14357#no2